# Not able to understand exponentiation using while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, bitwise-operators

```
def pow(base, exp):
    result = 1
    while exp:
        if exp & 1:
            result *= base
        exp >>= 1
        base *= base
    return result
```

1. Why do we divide the while loop in two parts when `exp & 1` and `exp >>= 1`?
2. I am not able to understand why I can't use `==` in place of `&` in the fourth line of code .It will give wrong output.
3. Why `exp >>= 1` and not `exp >= 1`?

Comment: I think you should first take a look at [`bitwise operators`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Why we divide the while loop in two part when 'exp & 1' and 'exp >>=1

Only the first of those makes a separation, as there is an `if` block. The second one is an assignment that is executed in each iteration of the loop, whether the first condition is true or not. The first condition determines whether we should add something to the temporary result or not.

> 2. I am not able to understand why I cant use '==' in place '&' in fourth line of code. It will throwing wrong output.

`==` would indeed be wrong. The `exp & 1` expression inspects (only) the least significant bit of `exp`. It would be equivalent to `exp % 2`. Both expressions evaluate to 1 when `exp` is odd, and to 0 when `exp` is even.

> 3. why 'exp>>=1' not 'exp>=1'

Because the second is not an assignment, but a comparison. The first is an assignment. It could be written more verbose as `exp = exp >> 1`. This shifts the bits of `exp` one position to the right, and is equivalent to `exp = exp // 2`.

### The algorithm

This algorithm is known as ["Exponentiation by squaring"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), and more precisely, the *iterative* version of the algorithm. See also the [example implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring#Example_implementations) in that Wikipedia article.

### Monitoring the algorithm

You could add some `print` calls to see how variables are evolving during the algorithm. For instance, like this:

```
def pow(base, exp):
    result = 1
    while exp:
        print("least significant bit of exp is {}".format(exp & 1))
        if exp & 1:
            print("  adapt result: {} * base {} => {}".format(result, base, result*base))
            result *= base
        print("shift exp (binary) {0:5b} => {1:5b}".format(exp, exp >> 1))
        exp >>= 1
        print("square base {} => {}".format(base, base*base))
        base *= base
    print("result {}".format(result))
    return result

result = pow(10, 6)
```

This outputs:

```
least significant bit of exp is 0
shift exp (binary)   110 =>    11
square base 10 => 100
least significant bit of exp is 1
  adapt result: 1 * base 100 => 100
shift exp (binary)    11 =>     1
square base 100 => 10000
least significant bit of exp is 1
  adapt result: 100 * base 10000 => 1000000
shift exp (binary)     1 =>     0
square base 10000 => 100000000
result 1000000
```

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Why do we divide the while loop in two parts when `exp & 1` and `exp >>= 1`?

Branching only happens on the former. `result *= base` is executed if `exp & 1` can be interpreted as true. `exp & 1` basically means "is `exp` odd?", so `reult *= base` will happen if `exp` is odd.

#### 2. I am not able to understand why I can't use `==` in place of `&` in the fourth line of code. It will give wrong output.

`exp & 1` isn't testing to see if `exp` equals 1, it's performing a [bitwise and](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) between `exp` and 1. As mentioned, this essentially just checks if `esp` is odd.

#### 3. Why `exp >>= 1` and not `exp >= 1`?

`exp >>= 1` is [bit-shifting](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) (same link as before) `exp` to the right by 1, not testing if it's greater than or equal 1.